# What does this mean in Matlab: x=x(: , N)

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, multidimensional-array

I have seen this in others code and cannot understand what this means `x=x(: , N)` where x is a 2D array, N is a 1D array

Here are some examples

```
test = [1,2;3,4];
ttt = [1,1,1,1 ,2,2,2,2];
test = test(:,ttt);
```

The result is:

```
1   1   1   1   2   2   2   2

3   3   3   3   4   4   4   4
```

and

```
test = [1,2;3,4];
ttt = [1,1,1,1 ,1,1,1,1];
test = test(:,ttt);
```

The result is:

```
1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1

3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3
```

Thank you!

Comment: http://www.vincentcheung.ca/research/matlabindexrepmat.html

It's mentioned here as having the same function as repmat.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`test(:,ttt)` means: from matrix `test` take all rows (`:`), and the columns indicated by `ttt`.

So in your first example (`ttt = [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2]`) you take the first column of `test` four times, then the second column four times. In the second example (`ttt = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]`) you take the first column of `test` eight times.

For more information about indexing in Matlab, see [here](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html).

Comment: Argh! Beaten again! There'll come a time when I just give up!

Answer (score 4):

Primarily the notation `x(:, N)` is used to index specific columns in `x` that are given by `N` as in

```
>> x = zeros(3, 3);
>> x(:) = 1:9;
>> N = [1 3];
>> x(:, N)
ans =

     1     7
     2     8
     3     9
```

Here `:` indexes all of the rows in `x` and `N` is used to index the columns `1` and `3` in `x`. Your example is an extension of this.

So in the next example because `1` occurs multiple times it indexes (and returns) that column of `x` for every time it occurs. Hence, why we see the first column that contains `1` and `3` 4 times.

```
>> x = [1 2; 3 4]
x =

     1     2
     3     4
>> N = [1 1 1 1];
>> x(:, N)
ans =

     1     1     1     1
     3     3     3     3
```

This final example in your question is another extension of this, except this time we also have `2`'s in `N` so we see the second column with `2` and `4` replicated.

```
>> x = [1 2; 3 4]
x =

     1     2
     3     4
>> N = [1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2];
>> x(:, N)
ans =

     1     1     1     1     2     2     2     2
     3     3     3     3     4     4     4     4
```

Next when we add in the `=` we are assigning the output of `x(:, N)` to `x` overwriting what was previously in it

```
>> x = x(:, N)
ans =

     1     1     1     1     2     2     2     2
     3     3     3     3     4     4     4     4
```